# Storing the results of unit test in python in some SQL Database

Tags: python, sql, unit-testing, testing, nose

I am learning the different possibilities to write and run (unit) tests in Python. I would like to store the output of the tests in a SQL database -preferably sqlite.

I found a way to run the tests using the nose framework from inside the code like this:

```
import nose
import os

os.chdir('./projects/project A')

result = nose.run()

print 'The result:', result
```

And I get the following output:

```
The result: True
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.013s

OK
```

I am forced to parse the stderr/stdout or is there any better way to get the test results and messages for further processing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `nosetests --with-xunit` to get the results in a  standard XUnit file format (XML). You can then parse and process that to insert it into a database.

You can also look for a third-party plugin that writes it in a different output format. The last option would be to write a plugin yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How can I run nose with this parameter from inside the python code ? Is there any other way, how to achieve the task without storing the results of the test in a file and parsing the file afterwards ? I does not have to stick with nose, would gladly use other testing framework/utility for this.

Comment: @karlitos: when you call `nose.run()` you can pass many options and configuration settings as well: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core.html?highlight=run#nose.core.run - so you can do the same thing inside the Python code, it's only a matter of passing the right parameters. I'm pretty sure other testing frameworks such as `py.test` have similar abilities but I'd need to investigate. Many testing frameworks have some way of allowing the test results to be parsed and processed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have to say I had much more success using the  [unittest — Unit testing framework](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)

Basically the TestRunner produces an instance of the class TestResult storing information about the tests.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    suites = [unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(KnownValues),
              unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ToRomanBadInput),
              unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(FromRomanBadInput),
              unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(CaseCheck)]

    # runs 12 test
    testResult = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=0).run(unittest.TestSuite(suites))

    print 'The errors: ', testResult.errors
    print 'The Failures: ', testResult.failures
    print 'The number of runs: ', testResult.testsRun
    print 'Test were successful: ', testResult.wasSuccessful()
```

produces this output:

```
The errors:  []
The Failures:  []
The number of runs:  12
Test suite was successful:  True
```

There is much more of it described in the documentation.